# pip install successful but commands do not work

Tags: python, linux, macos, unix, pip

I am trying to pip install a CLI and it successfully installs.

```
pip3 install databricks-cli
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: databricks-cli in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (0.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=6.7 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from databricks-cli) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.17.3 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from databricks-cli) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from databricks-cli) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate>=0.7.7 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from databricks-cli) (0.8.9)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->databricks-cli) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->databricks-cli) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->databricks-cli) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>=2.17.3->databricks-cli) (2020.12.5)
```

But when I go ahead and try to use a command I am given an error that it cannot find the command.

```
 ~ databricks --version
zsh: command not found: databricks
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed the following command.

```
sudo -H pip3 install databricks-cli
```